# Incompatible library version selenium / guava

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, guava

My app has a hard dependency on `com.google.guava:guava:23.3` or superior

```
+--- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:guava:2.6.0
|    +--- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.6.0
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava:23.3-jre (*)
```

But I am also using `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1` which is incompatible with guava versions > 22.0 as discussed here:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4381

I am pretty new to Java, what is the best course of action here ?

I have looked into class loaders but that looks like a pretty deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have a hard dependency on **`com.google.guava:guava:23.3`** using **`org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1`** may put you on cross roads. But *Selenium Release Notes* clearly mentions the following guava dependencies :

- **`Selenium v2.49.0`** : Bump guava to version 19
- **`Selenium v3.1.0`** : Requires an update to the  latest guava version 21.0
- **`Selenium v3.5.0`** : Bump guava to version 22.
- **`Selenium v3.5.1`** : Bump guava to version 23.
- **`Selenium v3.12.0`** : **guava-23.6-jre**
- **`Selenium v3.13.0`** : guava-25.0-jre
- **`Selenium v3.14.0`** : guava-25.0-jre
- **`Selenium v3.141.0`** : guava-25.0-jre
- **`Selenium v3.141.5`** : guava-25.0-jre
- **`Selenium v3.141.59`** : guava-25.0-jre

---

### Conclusion

So **`Selenium v3.12.0`** have got **guava-23.6-jre** which clearly fits to your requirement.

Comment: WHERE did you find the releasde notes with these dependencies? I'm trying to find them for 4.3.0 but they're nowhere to be found.