# No instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V> error using Selenium 3.13.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been using these 2 function in Selenium, they were working fine. Now they dont, there is an error saying:

```
No instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition<WebElement> conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>
```

I have not updated Selenium nor anything else in the project. 
What could be the cause?

worth mentioning, the function they both reside is:

```
public static void safeClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, Boolean checkVisibility) {
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();", element);

    if (checkVisibility) {
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }

   executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
No instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition<Boolean> 
conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>
```

...implies that there is a mismatch between the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) client version and [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) versions.

A bit more details about the *Selenium* client version and the *Guava* version you are using would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way.

---

### Solution

Ensure the following combination of *Selenium* client version and the *Guava* version:

- *Selenium v3.12.0* : **guava-23.6-jre**
- *Selenium v3.13.0* : **guava-25.0-jre**
- *Selenium v3.14.0* : guava-25.0-jre
- *Selenium v3.141.0* : guava-25.0-jre
- *Selenium v3.141.5* : guava-25.0-jre
- *Selenium v3.141.59* : guava-25.0-jre

---

### References

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Incompatible library version selenium / guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284776/incompatible-library-version-selenium-guava/50287063#50287063)

Comment: Tnx. I have downloaded guava 25 jar file but the problem still exists. 
I am now sure the version of the Rest Assured library II am using is not compatible with 3.13 Selenium. Do you know which version I have to use?

Comment: abbas did you get the solution for this problem?

Comment: I was having this problem with my wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(myGetElementFunction())) that was previously working but started giving the same error as OP when I cleared my .m2 folder and ran mvn install. This fixed my problem: I realized I didn't have guava installed, and I had to specifically get version 25.0-jre. Thanks!