# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.tolmmutableList() Ljava/util/stream/Collector error using Appium and Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, guava, nosuchmethoderror, reportportal

We are trying to integrate report portal with mobile automation framework. In the framework we are using Appium, Selenium and TestNG.
We have added Report portal dependencies and
at the time of execution, we can see the launches in report portal but the execution is getting failed with following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.tolmmutableList() Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.getW3C (NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:367)
```

We tried changing Appium and Report portal dependency versions.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.tolmmutableList() Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
```

...implies that there are conflicting/multiple versions of [**guava**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57658406/7429447) at play.

Possibly Report portal dependencies adds the second version of [*guava*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287063/7429447). Resolve the interdependency and you would be good to go.

Comment: I tried bellow solutions for conflicting/multiple versions of guava, but getting same error ..  1.
   <exclusion>
2.
<dependencyManagement> 
3.
maven-enforcer-plugin
And
 <DependencyConvergence/>